# How many $0$-s have at the end number $11^{11}22^{22}55^{55}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, contest-math

How many $0$-s have at the end number $11^{11}22^{22}55^{55}$.
This problem came up my contest math test .I couldn't answer this .I didn't have really any idea how to prove or what theorem could I use.  Will be thankful if you can help.

Comment: Hint:  the number of $0's$ at the end is exactly the order to which $10$ divides the number.

Comment: @lulu So there will be $22$ $0$'s?

Comment: That's right.  $\quad$

Comment: @unit1991 Right, in fact $\,11^{11}22^{22}55^{55}=5^{33}11^{88}\cdot 10^{22}\,$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the answer is simply whatever power of $10$ is contained in that number. Since

$$11^{11} 22^{22} 55^{55} = 11^{11} \cdot 2^{22} 11^{22} \cdot 5^{55} 11^{55}$$

we combine what powers of $2$ and $5$ that we can into $10^{22}$, giving $22$ as our answer.

Answer (score 3):

$10 = (2)(5)$, so you're only focusing on those prime factors. Ignore $11$ completely.

After full prime factorisation, you'll get $2^{22}\cdot 5^{55} \cdot 11^k$, where $k$ doesn't matter. You need to pair up a single $2$ with a single $5$ to get one factor of $10$ and, therefore, one trailing zero. The lower exponent is the limiting factor. So you need the minimum of the two exponents of interest, i.e. $\mathrm{min} (22,55) = 22$, so there will be $22$ zeroes, a conclusion you yourself have reached in the comments. The remaining "unpaired" $33$ instances of $5$ won't contribute any zeroes by themselves.